# Hide Flasgger endpoints based on auth

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to hide certain endpoints while the user is not logged in

for example, I want the /api/auth route to be always visible, but after logging in, routes such as /api/get_data should be visible

it seems straight forward but I can't find a solution that fits for my use case at all. Specifically, I am looking for a Flasgger implementation using JWT auth. My apidocs are defined as yaml files in the routes

```
class GetData(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    @jwt_required()
    def post():
        """
        file:/swagger/get_data.yml
        """
```

It would be really nice if I could add it to the yaml file, similar to this:

```
Get Data
---
security:
  - JWTAuth: []
tags:
  - name: Get Data
```

but this "security" section only adds a lock to the route. It would be perfect if this also hides the route if the user isnt logged in

my flasgger also uses the header "jwt-token" which is added to the response after login.

```
access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
resp.headers['jwt-token'] = access_token
```

I feel like all of this is setup so I could just add a "hidden_if_unauthorized" flag, but I can't find anything like that